# How can I avoid dynamic allocation when I need polymorphism?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

With GCC on Ubuntu 14.04 and the following MCVE:

```
class TargetInterface
{
public:
   ~TargetInterface();
   //
   DataBuffer retDataBuffer();
   // following methods are all pure virtual
   virtual void delay() = 0;
   // ...
protected:   
   DataBuffer dataBuffer;
}

class FlashTarget : public TargetInterface
{
   public:
   void delay() override;
   // ...
}   

// globals
TargetInterface * targetInterface;

void main()
{
    targetInterface = new FlashTarget; // <--
    // ...
    // etc.
}
```

`FlashTarget` is derived from `TargetInterface` and `targetInterface` is dynamically allocated in `main()`.

Is there a way to **avoid dynamic allocation** for the above code?

Comment: Put the `FlashTarget` object on the stack (or as a global; I'd rather avoid the globals completely, but if that's what you really want to do...). Why do you think you can't do that? Is this an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: `void main()` is not a standard prototype.

Comment: @BoBTFish: You mean smthing like: `targetInterface = &flash;` where: flash is: `FlashTarget flash` ?

Comment: @groenhen Sure, that would work.

Comment: Do you need a pointer for `targetInterface`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the naive answer:

```
void main()
{
    FlashTarget target;
    targetInterface = &target;
}
```

Note: with this approach, you *must* ensure that `target` will live as long as `targetInterface` is used.

Comment: Should I make `target` a global variable just to be on a safe side?

Comment: Only if the instancied `target` is used to initialize global variables. If your code works with the dynamic version, it should work with the stack variable.

Comment: Better to eliminate global variables entirely.     Take note that YSC described his approach as "naive".

Comment: You can run into problems if static objects uses `target` or `targetInterface` in their destructors, since static objects are destructed after `main` has executed, IIRC.

Comment: @Peter naive doesn't mean bad here. I used it as _with the information provided, the simplest solution which answer the question_. (just clarifying)

Comment: the solution is not to bury yourself even more. Figure out how `targetInterface` is used, what is it's scope and **make it non-global**. Then it would be easy to attach `target` to the scope of `targetInterface `

Comment: @YSC - I recognised you were answering the question as asked in the simplest manner possible.   And I didn't say `naive == bad`, simply that the use of globals is often a naive quick solution that is often better avoided.

Comment: @Peter ok we agree to each other